# Img src databinding returns 403

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am attempting to create an online reader application for comics using Vue.js and axios. In the code below I am trying to load the proper images from a CDN.

```
<template>
<div class="chapter">
    <div class="chapter-content">
        <img class="lazy" :src="'//cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/'+ chapter[n][1]" :srcset="'//cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/'+ chapter[n][1] ">
    </div>
    <div class="chapter-nav">
        <div class="btn">
            <button @click="n++" :disabled="n >= chapter[1].length - 1">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <button @click="n--" :disabled="n <= 0">Prev</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import { HTTP } from '../environment'

export default {
    name: "chapter",
    props: ['id'],

    data(){
        return {
            chapter: [],
            n:0,
        }
    },

    methods: {

        getChapter(id){
            var vm = this;
            HTTP.get('/chapter/'+ id)
                .then(function(response){
                    vm.chapter = response.data.images;
                    vm.lazyLoad();
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        },
    },

    created(){
        this.getChapter(this.id);
    },

    watch:{
        '$route'(){
            this.getChapter(this.id);
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

When opening my app in the browser, this returns a 403 Forbidden error. The issue that is rocking my brain, is that the image will load only when I open the image src in another tab in my browser. Then the app works just fine.

Comment: please give an example of  an `url`, or the `chapter[n][1]` example

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim Here is an example of a url from my app: https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/c5/c5b432a78c57f24e9ec9ba12484fe6bb82f773aede2ec4c9b84a51c3.jpg

Comment: in your ajax request did you get the correct path?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I did, in fact that is where I copied the previous url. If you wish to take a look at my app, it lives here: http://manga.thatdamn.net/#/

Comment: the server that provide these images doesn't allow you to use its images in your site

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim Initially, but when I open the link for the image in another tab, that specific image will then work in the app. Is it possible that the app is pulling the image from browser cache?

Comment: yes i think that

Comment: The foreign page may use a referrer-check technique... Are you allowed to use these images?

Comment: I just hit the same issue while trying to use Google user thumbnail photos / avatar images.